# Формат цен jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать цену такого формата `1.100.000` ?
Сейчас выводится вот так `1100000`.

```
$(function(){
$("#price").click(function(){
    var sum=0; // начальное значение можно указать любое
    $('#price :checked').each(function(){
        sum+=parseInt($(this).val());

    });
    $('.catalog-item__price-total span').text(sum + ' руб.');    
});
```

Comment: попробуйте https://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(изменил по правке MedvedevDev)

Можно вот так

```js
const a = 1100000;
console.log(a.toLocaleString('de-DE'));
```

Comment: Почему не просто `a.toLocaleString('de-DE')`?

Comment: Точно. Немцы рулят )

Comment: обновите ответ, что бы "верный" вариант был в самом ответе, а не в комментариях к нему )

Answer (score 1):

Более красивый вариант уже есть, но почему бы и нет, может для чего-то ещё пригодится xDD

```js
let newNum = '';
const num = 1100000.2345,
  separate = num.toString().split('.'),
  numArray = separate[0].split(''),
  numArrayLength = numArray.length;

for(let i = 0; i < numArrayLength; i++) {
  newNum += numArray[i] + ((numArrayLength - i - 1) % 3 === 0 && i + 1 !== numArrayLength ? '.' : '');
}

if(separate[1]) newNum += ',' + separate[1];

console.log(newNum);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/5xL15wgd/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $(".price").click(function(){
                var sum=0; // начальное значение можно указать любое
                $('.price:checked').each(function(){
                    sum+=parseInt($(this).val());
                });
                sum = (sum).formatMoney(0, '.', '.');

                $('span.catalog-item__price-total').text(sum + ' руб.');
            });

            Number.prototype.formatMoney = function(c, d, t){
                var n = this,
                        c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c,
                        d = d == undefined ? "." : d,
                        t = t == undefined ? "," : t,
                        s = n < 0 ? "-" : "",
                        i = String(parseInt(n = Math.abs(Number(n) || 0).toFixed(c))),
                        j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
                return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
            };
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="550000" class="price">
        550.000
    </label>

    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="550000" class="price">
        550.000
    </label>
    <br>

    <span class="catalog-item__price-total"></span>
</body>


</html>
```